# Re-submitting app after it's been accepted

Tags: xcode, app-store, submission

I've submitted an app that got accepted in it's 1.0 state, but I haven't published it because we had to wait for the next version.

Now I have the 1.01 version that I would like to submit, with a build number of 5 (the previous one on the store was 3), which I did using the following :

- Archive
- Distrubution to the app store
- Submit to the app store
- Submit to the appstore Complete, with a big green V.

5 hours after I still don't see my build or version on my itunes connect page, it still shows the old page as it always did.

Did I do something wrong? Must I publish before updating? I really wish we wouldn't' have to. Have I lost a day of review queue?

Thanks for your help

EDIT: Here is what I had at the end of my Xcode archive routine :

[image: The Xcode confirmation]

Yet nothing shows on the itunesconnect side, several hours afterwards.

Here is my build section in the version tab, which shows the version I uploaded two months ago. :
[image: description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you prepare a new version to send to apple review team? I mean in the itunes connect webpage.

**EDIT:** You have to reject your old binary that is "ready to publish" or if you want publish it ("ready for sale"). Then you have to re-upload your new binary, creating a new version tab. You can follow this steps to upload your new binary:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html

Comment: Yeah I have everything ready and submitted, or so I believe. Even though I have nothing showing in my itunes Connect account. Look at the edit I'll make in a second

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your itunes connect webpage, the part of the uploaded binary. Or follow this steps: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html

Comment: So you mean the "Version" tab, down to the "Build"  section?

Comment: Try to remove or publish your current build: Open the App Details page for the app, as described in Creating an iTunes Connect Record for an App.
On Versions, scroll down to the Build section.
Hover over the build and click the minus sign that appears to the right of the build number.

Comment: Nothing shows when I hover over the  build :( 
But shouldn't I see a new version tab with my 1.01 right next to 1.0 ? and have two separate tab with each version?

Comment: Yes, if your app is "ready for sale", you have to prepare a new tab with your new version.

Comment: So, i think you have to publish your app and create a new tab version, or reject the 1.0 version, create a new tab with 1.1 and wait until 10 days since apple accept the new version.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I'll probably reject the 1.0 just now.
But to make sure I understand your last bit, right now, my 1.1 is ALREADY in the queue ? right? So wether or not I reject the 1.1, when they're done reviewing I will get my 1.1 tab ? 100% sure?

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you have to reject the version that is "ready to publish" but you don't want to publish. Then you have to create a new tab version on itunes connect. "Prepare a new version" and then in your xcode upload your new binary (1.1). Before 5/10 minutes your binary will appear on your itunesconnect. The next step is to press "save" and "submit for review". After 7-10 days your app will be ready to publish or sale.

Comment: I just did that and I confirm this is a valid answer. Once I refused it it changed to the state " refused by developer ". I then removed the current build (3) and was able to find my build (5) in the list.
My previous upload was already there, I didn't have to re-archive or anything. :)

Comment: Great!! Now you have to wait one week more again, it s the slow process of the apple review team. :(